# file path Windows format to java format

Tags: java

I need to convert the file path in windows say C:\Documents and Settings\Manoj\Desktop  for java as C:/Documents and Settings/Manoj/Desktop  .

Is there any utility to convert like this.?

Comment: Can you why you need this?
Because generally in file handling java can take care of these conversions automatically...

Comment: @Nivas it gives File Not found error under Windows 10.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
String path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Manoj\\Desktop";
path = path.replace("\\", "/");
// or
path = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Find more details in the [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 14):

```
String path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Manoj\\Desktop";
String javaPath = path.replace("\\", "/"); // Create a new variable
```

or

```
path = path.replace("\\", "/"); // Just use the existing variable
```

`String`s are immutable. Once they are created, you can't change them. This means `replace` returns a new String where the target(`"\\"`) is replaced by the replacement(`"/"`). Simply calling `replace` will not change `path`.

The difference between [`replaceAll`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`replace`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) is that replaceAll will search for a regex, replace doesn't.

Answer (score 11):

Java 7 and up supports the `Path` class (in java.nio package).
You can use this class to convert a string-path to one that works for your current OS.

Using:

```
Paths.get("\\folder\\subfolder").toString()
```

on a Unix machine, will give you `/folder/subfolder`. Also works the other way around.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

Answer (score 3):

Just check

**in MacOS**

```
File directory = new File("/Users/sivo03/eclipse-workspace/For4DC/AutomationReportBackup/"+dir);
File directoryApache = new File("/Users/sivo03/Automation/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/webapps/AutomationReport/"+dir);
```

**and same we use in windows**

```
File directory = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\BrokenLinkCheckerALL\\AutomationReportBackup\\"+dir);
File directoryApache = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\Automation\\apache-tomcat-9.0.26\\webapps\\AutomationReports\\"+dir);
```

use double backslash instead  of single frontslash

so no need any converter tool just use find and replace

**"C:\Documents and Settings\Manoj\Desktop"**
to
"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Manoj\\Desktop"

Answer (score -6):

```
String path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\someDir";
path = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

In Windows  you should use four backslash  but not two.

Comment: to form String that represents correct regular expression that matches backslash four backslashes are needed and example is true in the context of replaceAll method that expects regex as argument, but generally it is not the case

Comment: Hm, why is this comment downvoted when the actual accepted answer is basically the same?

Comment: @guenhter Maybe because it was posted more than 6 years after the accepted answer and adds nothing new as it is, as you points out, the same. Posting a copy of an existing answer adds no value and only creates unnecessary noise

Comment: Makes sense. Thx