# file not found error when reading excel file in java

Tags: java

I am getting following error when I try to read an excel file in java although the file is present. I am in Windows environment. I have confirmed that that the file is present at that location.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\myfile.xls (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:213)
```

My code is as follows:

```
       wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:/myfile.xls"));
```

Comment: please ensure the case of the filename and extension in the file you have created.

Answer (score 2):

have tried with

```
   wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:\\myfile.xls"));
```

Al so see  :[File.separator or File.pathSeparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971964/file-separator-vs-pathseparator)

Make sure that your file is in D drive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have ensured that the file is present in D drive and the case and extension is right. I have also tried with  "D:\\myfile.xls", but I get same error.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059383/file-path-windows-format-to-java-format

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you my example, code has been tested and let me know if this works.

> File fileExcel = new File("D:/DATAVALUE.xls");
>
> Workbook w;
>
> w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fileExcel);
>     Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);

I tested this code and let me captured this one for you.

> /*  * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates  * and open
>   the template in the editor.  */ package stackoverflow;
>
> import java.io.File; import jxl.Cell; import jxl.Sheet; import
>   jxl.Workbook;
>
> /**  *  * @author jwijaya  */ public class Stackoverflow {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @param args the command line arguments
>  */
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     // TODO code application logic here
>     try
>                     {
>
>                     File fileExcel = new File("D:/tes.xls");
>                     Workbook w;
>                     w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fileExcel);
>                     Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
>
>                     for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getRows(); j++) {
>                         for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) {
>                             Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, j);
>
>
>                                                 if((j==0 && i==0 ) || (j==0 && i==1) ||  (j==0 && i==2) || (j==0 && i==3))
>                                                 {
>                                                 System.out.println("Isi tabel "
>                                                 + cell.getContents());
>                                                 }
>
>                         }
>                                                 Cell tanggal = sheet.getCell(0,j);
>                                                 String tanggalfinal = tanggal.getContents(); 
>                                                 System.out.println(tanggalfinal);
>
>                                                 Cell datausd = sheet.getCell(1,j);
>                                                 String datausdfinal = datausd.getContents(); 
>                                                 System.out.println(datausdfinal);
>
>                                                 Cell datajapan = sheet.getCell(2,j);
>                                                 String datajapanfinal = datajapan.getContents(); 
>                                                 System.out.println(datajapanfinal);
>
>
>                                                 Cell dataaus = sheet.getCell(3,j);
>                                                 String dataausfinal = dataaus.getContents(); 
>                                                 System.out.println(dataausfinal);
>
>
>
>                     }
>
>                     }
>                     catch (Exception e)
>                     {
>                     System.err.println("Got an exception!");
>                     System.err.println(e.getMessage());
>                     }
> } }
> ```

Download this file

```
https://hotfile.com/dl/204326337/3f04919/tes.xls.html
```

Comment: Don't forget to add your libraries. JXL

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have created file DATAVALUE.xls in D drive but  I still get the same error:                       java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\DATAVALUE.xls (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:213)
 at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)

Comment: Please accept this question if this is true, please save your document within the 97-2003 workbook then it will be xls I think you save within the xlsx format. After you try let me know

Comment: Thanks, but i am getting this error for any doc not only xls. Even if I create a notepad file, I get the same error.

Comment: Can anyone please help, I am unable to move ahead. I do not know why I am getting this error although the file is present at the location.

Answer (score 0):

In case you created the excel file beforehand, try to save it as a 97-2000 worksheet (So the old Excel format).