# Reading text file into Java array

Tags: java, arrays, text

So I'm trying to take a series of "scores" from a text file to put into an array and then sort in order, rows of four, and write other methods to get the highest, lowest, average, etc. The println commands are in there but I haven't written the methods yet. I've been working all day and I'm starting to confuse myself, and now I'm getting a NullPointerException error in the main method. Any help?

```
package arrayops1d;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayOps1D {

    static int scores[];
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/Steve/Documents/"
                + "NetBeansProjects/ArrayOps1D/Scores.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

        String scores = "";
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null){
            scores += line;
            line = reader.readLine();
        }


        System.out.println(scores);
        System.out.println(getTotal());
        System.out.println(getAverage());
        System.out.println(getHighest());
        System.out.println(getLowest());
        System.out.println(getMedian());
        System.out.println(getPosition());
        System.out.println(getDeviations);
        System.out.println(getStdDev);


}
```

Comment: can you post up your file content?

Comment: I do not get what your issue is? can you corporate and tell what is going on so we can help?

Comment: I don't see much code here, it look you are trying to read the entire file into one `String`. Why?

Comment: Can you post the error message youre getting?

Comment: With the limited code seen, it seems the scores[] variable is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

First Issue with your code: 
In your file path, Instead using `/` , you must use `\\` or better `File.separator` if your program wants to be ran in different platform.

If you do not , you will have `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

You are reading line by line, so you can use `split` Function and use `Integer.paraseInt` or `Float.parseFloat` to convert each splited elements and added to your array

1. [How to use Split in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)
2. [How to convert String to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java)

Comment: No. You can use "/" across platforms.

Comment: really? how come it does not work for me?

Comment: Yes. You'd have to give an example.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3059410/2970947) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can read the `int` values from a file into an array of `Integer` using a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) -

```
Integer[] scores = null;
File file = new File("C:/Users/Steve/Documents/"
        + "NetBeansProjects/ArrayOps1D/Scores.txt");
if (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
    try {
        List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                al.add(scanner.nextInt());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not an int: " + scanner.next());
            }
        }
        scores = al.toArray(new Integer[al.size()]);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Can't find file: " + file.getPath());
}
if (scores != null) {
    System.out.println("Scores Read: " + Arrays.toString(scores));
}
```

Comment: how do you expect when the OP shows this code to his or her teacher, the teacher can accept it?

Comment: It is not right to give the answer away. Just hint to lead the OP to the right palce and I am sure you agree with me

Comment: @KickButtowski Read OP's question again. There's a lot to this task besides reading the `int`(s) into an array. And OP actually posted code that appears to at least attempt it. It was either this, or show how to parse all of the `int`(s) from `String`(s) and frankly I think this `Scanner` example is pretty minimal.

Comment: I always admire you but I am sure you could put it as a hint. cuz the teacher gonna go nuts how novice student that could not write a function can go like this. If you read the question, the op has difficulty to write simple high score function. your code is too advance for the op and not helping him